# How can I take a .java file as a command line parameter?

Tags: java, eclipse, cmd, jar

I have a runnable `jar` file and a .java file. I want to make some processing on .java file (exp: how many operators or how many classes are there in .java file) and I can't take .java file as a parameter, It takes as a string. I wrote down:

C:\Users\aFurkan\eclipse-workspace\Odev1-1\dist>java -jar Program.jar Deneme1.java
Deneme1.java

But I want:
C:\Users\aFurkan\eclipse-workspace\Odev1-1\dist>java -jar Program.jar Deneme1.java
(Processes output from my code)

Comment: All command line parameters are Strings. You'll need to use the file name to create a File object and read it.

Comment: Or redirection `java -jar Program.jar < Deneme1.java` and then using `System.in` to read it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your program accepts input.

Case 1: You pass the File Name as a command line parameter, which it seems you're currently trying to do. If so, you need to use the given filename inside your program to open the corresponding file and read from that.

Case 2: You pass the contents of the file you're trying to process as text input via stdin. If so, you can tell the command line to do so using `<`, in your case `java -jar Program.jar < Deneme1.java`